# Facing Bad Request Issue when Creating A Model Set using AutoDesk API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, bim

We've initiated a request for creating a ModelSet using AutoDesk API (https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/modelset/v3/containers/:containerid/modelsets), but we're getting an error "BadInput".

[image: AJU_PETER_0-1695184645799.png]

We've initiated this same process manually using the AutoDesk webapp and it was a success.

[image: AJU_PETER_1-1695184794002.png]

We are able to fetch the ModelSet details using this (GET)API but we're unable to create a ModelSet using (POST) API.

[image: AJU_PETER_2-1695184939854.png]

The above image represents our folder structure.

Comment: A response to the aforementioned query would be greatly appreciated.